# How to solve online clustering problem

Tags: clustering, k-means

Suppose we have a clustering problem where data sample is of multi-dimension with a mix of `numeric` and `categorical` type.

If the problem is static i.e. we have all the data, then we can solve this problem by using `K-prototype` algorithm (variant of `K-Means` algorithm). But what if data comes dynamically, how can we solve this problem in such  cases

Possible constraints:

- Data comes dynamically
- Number of clusters is not fixed (it will increase with time)
- If `similarity(new_data_sample) < threshold` for all the clusters then the new cluster should be created containing `new_data_sample`

[image]

Comment: What you call dynamic is also commonly referred to as [online learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning)

Comment: Also, notice that the rule that you introduce in your third bullet point is [greedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) and might result in unnecessary high number of clusters. Think of examples where redefining one of the existing clusters to move a bit towards the new data point is better than just creating a new cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the existing methods on

### data stream clustering

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_stream_clustering